# UIProgressView not updating while my App loads its resources

Tags: uiview, uiprogressview

I am trying to update a UIProgressView progress bar that I have in a UIView during a long resource loading process. Let's say I'm loading a bunch of bitmaps from a NIB file (like maybe a hundred). After I load 10, I issue a .progress to the UIProgressView that is part of a UIView that is already being displayed. So, I issue:

```
myView.myProgressView.progress=0.2;
```

Then, I load another 10 bitmaps, and issue:

```
myView.myProgressView.progress=0.4;
```

etc., etc. When the app runs, the progress bar doesn't advance. It simply stays at its initial position. At the risk of sounding like a complete moron, do I have to load my resources on a separate thread so the OS can update the UI, or, is there an easier way? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Load them on a separate thread.  Or just use something like `performSelector`:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setProgressBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

(and create a `setProgressBar` function which reads the current value from a member variable and updates the UI)

Comment: Hi, Marcc,
I tried your performSelector approach to no avail. The setProgressBar method got called AFTER all my other code completed. I didn't even try to update the UIProgressView. I simply put an NSLog in setProgressBar and that came out on the console AFTER all the other resource loading methods. Any other suggestions ? Can you point me to a reference for maybe doing all this stuff on another thread ?

Comment: Oops.  So the idea is right, you need to update the data on one thread and not block the main thread (UI thread) while doing it.  I think you actually need to use performSelectorOnMainThread if you take this approach (search in the developer site for the docs on this one).

Answer (score 0):

You could run a step of the runloop after each update of the UI:

```
SInt32 result;
do {
    result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, TRUE);
} while(result == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
```

It could have other bad consequences (for example, enable user to interact with the UI, execute delegates of view controller such as `viewDidAppear` before they should be executed, etc) so be very, very careful.